# Send mail od multiple email addresses

Tags: php, html

I have an `HTML` form where the client can submit a form, and that form should arrive on my email and as well on the client mail.

This is a part of the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formName">
    <input type="text" name="client_email" placeholder="Email *" required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the part of the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $client_email = $_POST['client_email'];

    $mail_to = array(
        'my_email@test.com',
        $client_email
    );

    mail(implode(', ', $mail_to), $subject, $body, $header);
}
```

I'm not sure why I don't get any emails. I don't get any error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

as per your input box name is email.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formName">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email *" required>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

so you have to use same name in your php code.

```
$client_email = $_POST['email'];
```

**Use this code.**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $client_email = $_POST['email'];

    $mail_to = array(
        'my_email@test.com',
        $client_email
    );

    mail(implode(', ', $mail_to), $subject, $body, $header);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to set properly here the name of the field for email. But that is not a problem since the name is `cliend_name` as well. I've re-edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

To send to multiple recipients you could either to send separate emails, use the `CC` or `BCC` header in the construction of the message or concatenate multiple email addresses into a comma separated string.

It is not necessary for the `FROM` field to be present but you should do so to help avoid emails being classified as SPAM.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){

        $email=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
        if( $email ){

            $from='webmaster@domain.com';
            $subject='A monkey stole my banana';
            $message=implode( PHP_EOL, $_POST );

            $to=implode(',', array(
                'my_email@test.com', $email
            ));
            $headers=sprintf(
                "From: %s\r\n"
                $from
            );

            $status=@mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        }
    }
?>

<form method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email *' required>
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: This is a good example, but I don't need `BC` or `BCC`, I just need for the client to get the same email as me.